# How to get Envelope ID for Embedded Signing with DocuSign Rest API?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, docusignapi

I need to have Envelope ID for Embedded Signing with DocuSign API. I am integrating DocuSign using express.js at the back-end. 
The URL for post would look like this:

`POST /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient`

Here is the link where I came to know this, https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign.
I am not much experienced with DocuSign API, So I really need to know how I can get `envelopeId` for this because it is required for POST method. I would be highly grateful for your help. You can ask questions in the comments if you don't understand something about my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The envelope needs to be created first. The envelope creation API call will return an envelopeID, which you will then use as a parameter to start the embedded signing via the POST referenced above.

Comment: Okay. Great. Fair enough. But what POST URL I would use for envelope creation in Embedded Signing?

Comment: Use the Envelopes: create method to create an envelope. See https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST API References/Send+an+Envelope.htm